# Prove that $\sqrt{A_1A_2} + \sqrt{B_1B_2} \leq \sqrt{A_1 + B_1}\sqrt{A_2 + B_2}$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the below inequality using the AM-GM inequality, but I can't see how to get it to come out.

$$\sqrt{A_1A_2} + \sqrt{B_1B_2} \leq \sqrt{A_1 + B_1}\sqrt{A_2 + B_2}$$

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Can you only use AM-GM? Cauchy looks simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any positive real numbers $A_1,A_2,B_1$ and $B_2$ AM-GM inequality implies
\begin{align*}
2\sqrt{A_1A_2B_1B_2}&\le A_1B_2+A_2B_1
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
A_1A_2+2\sqrt{A_1A_2B_1B_2}+B_1B_2&\le A_1A_2+A_1B_2+A_2B_1+B_1B_2\\
\left(\sqrt{A_1A_2}+\sqrt{B_1B_2}\right)^2&\le\left(A_1+B_1\right)\left(A_2+B_2\right)
\end{align*}
So
$$\sqrt{A_1A_2}+\sqrt{B_1B_2}\le\sqrt{A_1+B_1}\sqrt{A_2+B_2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You first square both sides and then apply $AM-GM$ inequaity to the quantities $A_1B_2$ and $A_2B_1$